# VBA - How to filter for french words or another language with accents

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro that has to autofilter for specific words for a number of languages. However since VBA does not read unicode I have had to be creative in filtering for languages such as Japanese. I recorded myself filtering for はい and within the recorded macro it denoted this as "‚Í‚¢". I was able to use this same method to essentially have VBA read and output in Japanese.

I am working on the other languages now and have run into a wall as this same method does not seem to work with languages with accents. For example in French, d'enchères, simply is recorded as d'encheres so when I run the macro it does not find d'enchères.

2 part question:
1) What language/code is "‚Í‚¢"? Why is VBA able to read and display this as はい but I cannot directly input はい into my code?
2) Any suggestions on a way for me to autofilter for specific words that contain accents?

Any help is appreciated, as I am a novice!

Comment: 1. Just do a google search like : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8D .2. Use `strconv` and `char` to read word's characters word by word and test if its outside your language.

Comment: 1) What I mean by that is VBA is able to read "‚Í‚¢" as "はい". If I put "はい" into a msgbox it will display as "???" but if I input it as "‚Í‚¢" it will display as "はい". So I am curious if this combination of symbols is part of a language like ASCII? I'm not too sure.